# How to serve static page + react app on same URL like Twitter or FB?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, server-side-rendering, next.js

Is it possible to render a static web page if not signed in, but load the SPA (ReactJS) somehow if signed in before?  Or are those 'static' web page just part of the app?

What I mean is like Twitter.com or Facebook.com and how they either load the app immediately if you have signed in before, or a default page that is crawl-able.

Is server-side rendering the only answer? Or is there a simpler solution, since most search engine can crawl JavaScript site?  I do not want to use a subdomain like app.domain.com if possible.

Idea: most ReactJS tutorials start out with a rather empty index.html with a div that React should renders into.  How about a bootstrap html that has actual content and if React detects the user has already logged in then remove those static content dynamically?  Is this commonly done? what's the drawback?

Comment: The first HTTP request usually has a server-side check and you can set the router in the SPA to respond accordingly

Comment: Did you figure this out at some point? I am dealing with a similar issue right now and would love to hear if you have an idea on how to do this propery

Answer (score 0):

This can be solve by using if else condition in react js.

Hope you get user information from an api.

if api give you some user information then you can store that information in state and display them.

and if that state is null then you can display your static page.

By this you can render static page and react js on same page.

Hope this ans will solve your problem